# Passing a function as an argument to another function

Tags: c++

Why can a function like this

```
typedef std::vector<someclass> infocontainer;

double function2(const infocontainer&);

void function1(std::ostream&, const std::string&, double function2(const infocontainer&), const infocontainer, const infocontainer);
```

when called in main runs fine

```
function1(std::cout, "astring", function2, did, didnt);
```

But when function2 has a second argument it produces an error.

```
double function2(const infocontainer&, std::string&);

void function1(std::ostream&, const std::string&, double function2(const infocontainer&, const std::string&), const infocontainer, const infocontainer);
```

main

```
function1(std::cout, "astring", function2, did, didnt);

candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'double (const infocontainer &, const
  std::string &)' to 'double (*)(const infocontainer &, std::string &)' for 3rd argument
```

Comment: Can you give us a valid code example including how you call `function1` in your program.

Comment: @0x499602D2. Yes sorry I forgot to add the `function1` call for the second example.

Comment: I was missing `const` in `function2`.

Answer (score 3):

"no known conversion from"

```
double (const infocontainer &, const  std::string &)
```

"to"

```
double (*)(const infocontainer &, std::string &)
```

The difference is in `const` to second argument. You may think that the function is defined as `double function2(const infocontainer&, const std::string&);` but your compiler disagrees.

Answer (score 1):

`typedef` is your friend with function pointers.
The `typedef` will reduce a lot of problems especially when specifying parameters for a function.

### Example:

```
typedef double (*Pointer_To_One_Argument_Function)(const infocontainer&);  
typedef double (*Pointer_To_Two_Argument_Function)(const infocontainer&, std::string&);  

void function1A(std::ostream&, const std::string&, Pointer_To_One_Argument_Function, const infocontainer, const infocontainer);  
void function1B(std::ostream&, const std::string&, Pointer_To_Two_Argument_Function, const infocontainer, const infocontainer);
```

In the above example, the `typedef` can make the declarations more readable.
Also, changing the type of the parameter is easier should you choose to change the number or types of the parameters for the function pointer.

As for your question, examine the syntax of the function pointer in your two parameter function pointer example.

### Alternative: Function Objects (functors)

Rather than using the complex or complicated syntax for a function pointer, the C++ language offers another alternative:  Function objects.
A function object is a `class` or `struct` that has an `overloaded operator()`.
**Example:**

```
struct Function_Object_One_Parameter
{
   virtual double operator()(const infocontainer&) = 0;
};

struct Function_Object_Two_Parameter
{
   virtual double operator()(const infocontainer&, std::string&) = 0;
};

void function1C(std::ostream&, const std::string&, Function_Object_One_Parameter& f1, const infocontainer ic, const infocontainer)
{
  // ...
  f1(ic);
  // ...
}

void function1D(std::ostream&, const std::string& s, Function_Object_Two_Parameter& f2, const infocontainer ic, const infocontainer)
{
  // ...
  f2(ic, s);
  // ...
}
```

To use this pattern, declare functions derived from `Function_Object_One_Parameter` or `Function_Object_Two_Parameter`:

```
struct Happy_Function_One
: public Function_Object_One_Parameter
{
  double  operator()(const infocontainer&)
  {
    std::cout << "Happy" << std::endl;
    return 3.14159267;
  }
}
```

Comment: What about std::function?

Answer (score 1):

Because the code you have posted is not the same that the code you are trying to compile.

The following line

```
void function1(std::ostream&, const std::string&, double function2(const infocontainer&, const std::string&), const infocontainer, const infocontainer);
```

is missing a `const` before `std::string &` in the third parameter in the code you are trying to compile.